# Django m2m form save " through " table

Tags: django, forms, m2m

I'm having trouble in saving a m2m data, containing a 'through' class table.
I want to save all selected members (selected in the form) in the through table.
But i don't know how to initialise the 'through' table in the view.

my code:

```
class Classroom(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 'classroom_creator')
     classname = models.CharField(max_length=140, unique = True)
     date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
     open_class = models.BooleanField(default=True)
     members = models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name="list of invited members", through = 'Membership')

class Membership(models.Model): 
      accept = models.BooleanField(User)
      date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True) 
      classroom = models.ForeignKey(Classroom, related_name = 'classroom_membership')
      member = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 'user_membership')
```

and in the view:

```
def save_classroom(request):
   classroom_instance = Classroom()
   if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ClassroomForm(request.POST, request.FILES, user = request.user) 
        if form.is_valid():
           new_obj = form.save(commit=False)
           new_obj.user = request.user 
           new_obj.save()
           membership = Membership(member = HERE SELECTED ITEMS FROM FORM,classroom=new_obj)

           membership.save()
```

How should I initialise the membership for the Membership table to be populated right?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In case of using normal m2m relation (not through intermediary table) you could replace:

```
membership = Membership(member = HERE SELECTED ITEMS FROM FORM,classroom=new_obj)
membership.save()
```

with

```
form.save_m2m()
```

But in case of using intermediary tables you need to manually handle POST data and create Membership objects with all required fields ([similar problem](http://groups.google.com/group/django-users/browse_thread/thread/e1b6a4d856aed6af)). The most basic solution is to change your view to something like:

```
def save_classroom(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ClassroomForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
           new_obj = form.save(commit=False)
           new_obj.user = request.user 
           new_obj.save()

           for member_id in request.POST.getlist('members'):
                membership = Membership.objects.create(member_id = int(member_id), classroom = new_obj)
           return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = ClassroomForm()
    return render_to_response('save_classroom.html', locals())
```

Note how request.POST is manipulated (.getlist). This is because post and get are [QueryDict](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects) objects which has some implications (request.POST['members'] will return always one object!).

You can modify this code to get it more reliable (error handling etc.), and more verbose, eg:

```
member = get_object_or_404(User, pk = member_id)
membership = Membership.objects.create(member = member , classroom = new_obj)
```

But note that you are performing some db queries in a loop which is not a good idea in general (in terms of performance).

Comment: that was it! It really created me some headaches, as i'm quite new to python.
Thnx a lot!

Comment: Question: If i want to add the creator of the classroom as a member (the required.user), and to that list, how can i do it?
Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if I got your point. Either you can create new membership object (outside the loop) to create new connection between user and classroom (membership = Membership.objects.create(member = request.user, classroom = new_obj)
) or you can pass extra member_id(which is id of request.user) in POST and relation user-classroom will be created with use of existing code (for loop). For the second option you need to store request.user.id in some hidden field in your form.

Comment: yes! that was it! i was hesitating in double declarating the 'membership', but it is the right solution! thanks again!

Comment: Sorry to re-raise a question from years ago but what if you want to update rather than create a record? If a record already exist, doesn't objects.create add a new record rather than update?

Answer (score 5):

Like what dzida did, but use form.cleaned_data instead of request.post:

```
def save_classroom(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ClassroomForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
           new_obj = form.save(commit=False)
           new_obj.user = request.user
           new_obj.save()

           for member in form.cleaned_data['members'].all():
                Membership.objects.create(member = member,  classroom = new_obj)

           return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = ClassroomForm()
    return render_to_response('save_classroom.html', locals())
```

You also need to consider some memberships might be deleted, so:

```
def save_classroom(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ClassroomForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
           new_obj = form.save(commit=False)
           new_obj.user = request.user
           new_obj.save()

           final_members = form.cleaned_data['members'].all()
           initial_members = form.initial['members'].all()

           # create and save new members
           for member in final_members:
                if member not in initial_members:
                    Membership.objects.create(member = member,  classroom = new_obj)

           # delete old members that were removed from the form
           for member in initial_members:
               if member not in final_members:
                   Membership.objects.filter(member = member, classroom = new_obj).delete()

           return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = ClassroomForm()
    return render_to_response('save_classroom.html', locals())
```

If you use model forms (like in a generic CBV: `form_class=ClassroomForm`), override and put the saving logic above in the `save` method, something like:

```
ClassroomForm(forms.ModelForm):
    members = ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Classroom.objects.all(),
        widget=SelectMultiple
    )

    def save(self, commit=True):
        classroom = super().save(commit=False)
            if commit:
                classroom.save()
                if 'members' in self.changed_data:
                   final_members = self.cleaned_data['members'].all()
                   initial_members = self.initial['members']

                   # create and save new members
                   for member in final_members:
                        if member not in initial_members:
                            Membership.objects.create(member = member,  classroom = new_obj)

                   # delete old members that were removed from the form
                   for member in initial_members:
                       if member not in final_members:
                           Membership.objects.filter(member = member, classroom = new_obj).delete()

         return classroom
```

Answer (score 1):

You also need to specify the classroom for the membership:

```
membership = Membership(member = request.user,
                        classroom=new_obj) #if new_obj if your classroom
membership.save()
```

I guess you should also remove `User` in `accept = models.BooleanField(User)`. It shouldn't be necessary to set the date upon saving if you are using `auto_now`! But maybe `auto_now_add is more likely what you need (http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField)

Comment: thanks  it seems the natural solution, the problem is that new_obj - my classroom is not created yet, i guess.
now i've added the above declaration after new_obj.save(), and the new error is:   Cannot set values on a ManyToManyField which specifies an intermediary model.  Use Membership's Manager instead. :)

Comment: Try with Membership.objects.create() then, but do not forget to specify the classromm object!

Comment: Sorry to re-raise a question from years ago but what if you want to update rather than create a record? If a record already exist, doesn't objects.create add a new record rather than update?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it in a generic UpdateForm class-based view (django 1.8) for a similar yet different application using the form_valid method.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    """
    If the form is valid, save the associated model.
    """
    self.object.members.clear()
    self.object = form.save(commit=False)
    self.object.user = self.request.user 
    self.object.save()

    list_of_members = form.cleaned_data['members']

    ClassRoom.objects.bulk_create([
            Membership(
                Course=self.object,
                member=member_person,
                order=num)
            for num, member_person in enumerate(list_of_members)
        ])
    return super(ModelFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)
```