# django Cannot set values on a ManyToManyField which specifies an intermediary model. Use Manager instead

Tags: django, forms, m2m

i am working on saving on the same form two tables - having a m2m relation.
I don't succeed, my error persists with something like: Cannot set values on a ManyToManyField which specifies an intermediary model.  Use Membership's Manager instead
where Membership is my 'through table'.

my code :

```
def save_classroom(request):
   classroom_instance = Classroom()
   if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ClassroomForm(request.POST, request.FILES, user = request.user) 
        if form.is_valid():
           new_obj = form.save(commit=False)
           new_obj.user = request.user 
           new_obj.save()
           membership = Membership(member = request.user,classroom=new_obj)
           membership.save() 
           form.save_m2m()
           return HttpResponseRedirect('.')    
   else:
           form = ClassroomForm(user = request.user)     
   return render_to_response('classroom/classroom_form.html', {
           'form': form,

           }, 
          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

my models:

```
class Classroom(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 'classroom_creator')
     classname = models.CharField(max_length=140, unique = True)
     date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
     open_class = models.BooleanField(default=True)
     members = models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name="list of invited members", through = 'Membership')

class Membership(models.Model): 
      accept = models.BooleanField(default=False)
      date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True) 
      classroom = models.ForeignKey(Classroom, related_name = 'classroom_membership')
      member = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name = 'user_membership')
```

where am i wrong?

Comment: i'm editing now, and adding the models. thanks!

Comment: Related question has a solution at ORM level: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22964448/add-for-manytomanyfield-which-specifies-an-intermediary-model

Comment: Seems this question asked twice, see my answer to the other: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40822731/2863603

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As seen on:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany

> Unlike normal many-to-many fields, you can't use add, create, or assignment (i.e., beatles.members = [...]) to create relationships

I guess your code trips up on the line "form.save_m2m()", which is unnecessary since you already manually create a membership.

Comment: How are you able to save to a through table? I have a similar problem where save() does not work.

Comment: I am using Django 1.8 and after waisting almost 2 days nothing works. I have followed all the steps mentioned in the documentation(https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany). But nothing work, So finally I have decided to remove M2M relationship from source Model(i.e Classroom in your case) and just created a intermediate Model. Now its working fine, I am able to save and retrieve the associated data.

Answer (score 37):

If you are allowed to modify `class Membership`, adding `auto_created = True` might solve your problem,

```
class Membership(models.Model): 
    class Meta:
        auto_created = True
```

In Django 1.7, the error message is changed to "Cannot set values on a ManyToManyField which specifies an intermediary model". The solution is the same.

NOTE: This will remove your intermediate model entirely, and all the additional fields with it.

Comment: This worked for me, but after resetting database, an strange error occur : relation "app_membership" does not exist

Comment: When I do a "makemigrations" after adding the "auto-created" attribute, django wants to remove my own intermediarry model class. Why ?

Comment: @Raphael, it didn't happen to me. It might be another question entirely. (sorry my answer might not be very helpful, but I thought at least give you a quick reply.)

Comment: Django indeed removes intermediary model when using auto_created. Also, it is nowhere documented - so probably not wise to use it.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar error message on a different problem. I post it here just in case it helps others.

I've added a new `ManyToManyField` on an existing model. This model was used in a `ModelForm` built with an `exclude` field.

I fixed the problem by add the new field in the excluded ones.

Answer (score 3):

As of the [Django 2.2 release](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/releases/2.2/) you can also specify a `through_defaults` on the field in order to use add, create and assignment:

> The `RelatedManager.add()`, `create()`, `remove()`, `set()`, `get_or_create()`,
>   and `update_or_create()` methods are now allowed on many-to-many
>   relationships with intermediate models. The new `through_defaults`
>   argument is used to specify values for new intermediate model
>   instance(s).

In your case since all the fields already have defaults it might just work in 2.2.

Comment: Any usage examples? Can't find it anywhere

Comment: there are some examples in this section of the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

Answer (score 0):

As specified in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/

"Unlike normal many-to-many fields, you can’t use add(), create(), or set() to create relationships"

This means for django version 2.1 ,these methods are impossible. But the same page of django 2.2 documentation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/ tells that:

"You can also use add(), create(), or set() to create relationships, as long as you specify through_defaults for any required fields"

So just update the django to 2.2 or newer versions to use the above methods and while creating objects give the argument 'through_defaults' as a python dictionary with keys as your extra field names and values as their default values.