# Django - What's a good way to handle manytomany with intermediary table in forms and views

Tags: django, many-to-many, has-many-through

Suppose I have the following models -

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12,decimal_places=2)

class Organization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Item, through='Customizable')

class Customizable(models.Model):
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization)
    item = models.ForeignKey (Item)
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12,decimal_places=2)
```

More often than not, when `items` are "assigned" to an `organization`, they will have the same value as originally recorded in the related `Item` object. But in certain cases, an item assigned to an organization may have an overridden `value` (hence the intermediary model). Since overriding the original value happens rarely (but it does happen) I want to allow the user to simply select desired `items` from a list of `Item` instances to assign them to an organization instance. The user will then have the option of overriding individual values later after bulk assignment is complete.

So I have the following simple ModelForm -

```
class AssignItemsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    items = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Item.objects.all(),required=False,widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
    class Meta:
        model = Organization
        exclude = ('name',)
```

Now since I have a `through` model, a simple form.save() won't work. I need to
(i) save `Customizable` instances corresponding to the items selected by the user and 
(ii) make sure the persisted `Customizable` instances have the proper `value` taken from the corresponding `value` taken from the `item` instance related by foreignkey .

I am trying to handle it in a view (but my mind is blocked) -

```
def assign_items(request, oid):
    organization = Organization.objects.get(id=oid)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AssignItemsForm(data=request.POST, instance=organization)
        if form.is_valid():
            current_organization = form.save(commit=False)
            #
            #placeholder to save Customizable instances here
            #
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('redirect-someplace-else'))
    else:
        form = AssignItemsForm(instance=organization,)
    return render_to_response("assign_items.html", {"form": form,}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use `save_m2m` method:

```
def assign_items(request, oid):
    organization = Organization.objects.get(id=oid)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AssignItemsForm(data=request.POST, instance=organization)
        if form.is_valid():
            current_organization = form.save(commit=False)

            current_organization.save()

            form.save_m2m()

            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('redirect-someplace-else'))
    else:
        form = AssignItemsForm(instance=organization,)
    return render_to_response("assign_items.html", {"form": form,}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Look here for more info:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method

Comment: Not really. It's the stuff that I need to do *before* save_m2m is what I'm banging my head against.

Answer (score 0):

I'd approach this in a different way. You have an intermediary model for your m2m. Hence I'd argue that `AssignItemsForm` should be backed by this intermediary model. Therefore I'd change it as follows:

```
# forms.py
class AssignItemsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    value = forms.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, required = False)

    class Meta:
        model = Customizable
```

Next, the matter of allowing users to choose a different value. In order to do this I've made the `value` field of the model optional (`required = False`). I then check if the user has supplied an explicit value. If not I assume that the `Item`'s default value is to be used. For this I am overriding the `clean` method of the form:

```
    def clean(self):
        super(AssignItemsForm, self).clean()
        value, item = self.cleaned_data.get('value'), self.cleaned_data.get('item')
        if not value:
            value = item.value
        self.cleaned_data['value'] = value
        return self.cleaned_data
```

And finally I tested this in admin.

```
# admin.py
from app.forms import AssignItemsForm

class CAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = AssignItemsForm

admin.site.register(Item)
admin.site.register(Organization)
admin.site.register(Customizable, CAdmin)
```

This way you can continue to use `form.save()` thereby avoiding custom manipulation in the view. You'll have to change your view a bit to make sure that the organization is auto selected for assigning items.

```
# views.py
def assign_items(request, oid):
    organization = Organization.objects.get(id=oid)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AssignItemsForm(data=request.POST.copy())
        form.save()
    else:
        form = AssignItemsForm(initial = {'organization': organization})
    ...
```

Comment: Since overriding of values does not happen that often, I really want the user to be able to assign many items to an organization at one go. I think it would be just more convenient for the user in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Override the `save` method of the ModelForm. This way you won't have to repeat yourself if you need to use the form in multiple places.

See this answer for more details:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40822731/2863603