# How to save a ManyToMany field with a through relationship

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, many-to-many

I have the following models with a `ManyToMany` and `through` relationship:

```
class Meeting(models.Model):
    site = models.ForeignKey(Site)
    meeting_title = models.CharField(default='', max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    meeting_visitors = models.ManyToManyField(Visitor, through="MeetingArrival", blank=False, null=False) 

class Visitor(models.Model):
    visitor_company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
    visitor_name = models.CharField(default='', max_length=128, blank=False, null=False)

class MeetingArrival(models.Model):
    visitor = models.ForeignKey(Visitor)
    meeting = models.ForeignKey(Meeting)
    arrival_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I have a form to create a meeting:

```
class AddMeetingForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Meeting
        exclude = ['site',]
```

And a simple view to save the form:

```
def add_meeting(request): 
    add_meeting_form = AddMeetingForm(request.POST or None)
    site = Site.objects.get(user=request.user.id)

    if request.method == "POST":
        if add_meeting_form.is_valid():

            obj = add_meeting_form.save(commit=False)
            obj.site = site
            obj.save()
```

This saves the form, but not the `meeting_visitors` field, even though this field renders perfectly in the view. How do I save this relationship?

**EDIT**

If I add `add_meeting_form.save_m2m()` to the view, I get `Cannot set values on a ManyToManyField which specifies an intermediary model.  Use meetings.MeetingArrival's Manager instead.`. How would I do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**You will have to explicitly save the `MeetingArrival` object in your view to save an intermediate model in case of a `ManyToManyField` with `through` argument.**

For Django versions 2.1 and below, in case of `ManyToManyField` with an intermediary model, you can’t use `add`, `create`, or `assignment` which are available with normal many-to-many fields.

As per the [Django 1.8 docs:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships)

> Unlike normal many-to-many fields, you can’t use add, create, or
> assignment to create relationships.
>
> The only way to create this type of relationship is to create
> instances of the intermediate model.

So, you will have to explicitly create a `MeetingArrival` object in your view.

You can do it by:

```
def add_meeting(request): 
    add_meeting_form = AddMeetingForm(request.POST or None)
    site = Site.objects.get(user=request.user.id)

    if request.method == "POST":
        if add_meeting_form.is_valid():
            obj = add_meeting_form.save(commit=False)
            obj.site = site
            obj.save()

            # create an instance of 'MeetingArrival' object
            meeting_arrival_obj = MeetingArrival(meeting=obj, visitor=<your_visitor_object_here>, arrival_status=True)
            meeting_arrival_obj.save() # save the object in the db
```

Comment: Thanks, how do I get `your_visitor_object_here`? The form input is a multiple selection.

Comment: We can write the logic to get the visitor object in the view. Since, `Visitor` is a foreign key, you can find which `MeetingArrival` is related to which `Visitor`  and then use that `Visitor` to create a `MeetingArrival` object.

Comment: Thanks. If I have another `ManyToMany` field that is not a `through` field, how would I save the form then? e.g. ` meeting_team_members = models.ManyToManyField(Team, blank=False, null=False)`

Comment: You can do that simply by `.add()`. Lets say `ABC` is the model of `meeting_team_members`. Then you can do `abc_object.meeting_team_members.add(team_object)`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58985327/117268 for a simpler way to do this in > Django 2.0.

Answer (score 7):

for django 1.x, it is as what Rahul said that you can't use `add`, `create`, etc

for django 2.x, you actually can per the document here [django 2.x](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships)

> You can also use add(), create(), or set() to create relationships, as long as you specify through_defaults for any required fields:
>
> ```
> beatles.members.add(john, through_defaults={'date_joined': date(1960, 8, 1)})
> beatles.members.create(name="George Harrison", through_defaults={'date_joined': date(1960, 8, 1)})
> beatles.members.set([john, paul, ringo, george], through_defaults={'date_joined': date(1960, 8, 1)})
> ```

Answer (score 3):

When you use a *through* table, you need to save there manually.

```
MeetingArrival.objects.create( ... )
```

Comment: Thanks, could you give an example please?

Answer (score 1):

Don't put the logic where you handle the ManyToManyField in your view, put it in your form instead, so you won't have to repeat yourself if you use the form in multiple places.

To this end, you need to override the `save` method of the `ModelForm`.

See my more thorough answer to another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40822731/2863603

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way, still trying to get multiple id values from the select, I think there is something wrong in my javascript

but here is python code:

```
class ArticuloCreateView(View):
    def __init__(self):
        self.template_name = 'articulo/formulario.html'

    def get(self, request):
        formulario = ArticuloForm()
        contexto = {
            'form': formulario,
            'operation': "Nuevo"
        }
        return render(request, self.template_name, contexto)

    @transaction.atomic
    def post(self, request):
        punto_transaccion = transaction.savepoint()
        formulario = ArticuloForm(request.POST)
        almacenes = request.POST.get('almacenes', 0)
        almacenes = Almacen.objects.filter(id=almacenes)

        if formulario.is_valid():
            datos_formulario = formulario.cleaned_data
            articulo = Articulo()
            articulo.clave = datos_formulario.get('clave')
            articulo.descripcion = datos_formulario.get('descripcion')
            articulo.tipo = datos_formulario.get('tipo')
            articulo.udm = datos_formulario.get('udm')
            articulo.clave_jde = datos_formulario.get('clave_jde')
            articulo.save()

            for almacen in almacenes:
                Stock.objects.create(articulo=articulo, almacen=almacen)
            if punto_transaccion:
                transaction.savepoint_commit(punto_transaccion)

            return redirect(
                reverse('inventarios.articulos_lista')
            )
        contexto = {
            'form': formulario,
        }

        return render(request, self.template_name, contexto)
```

Answer (score 0):

user_profiles = UserProfile.objects.all()

NotificationUser.objects.bulk_create([NotificationUser(user=user_profile,  notification=notification) for user_profile in user_profiles])