# Django auto save m2m relationship in form using through table

Tags: python, django

I have a m2m relationship between `Servers` and `Products` in Django with a through table called `ServerProducts`.

```
class ServerProduct(TimeStampedModel):
     # Additional fields may be required in the future
     server = models.ForeignKey('Server', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     product = models.ForeignKey('Product', on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Server(TimeStampedModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    # ...
    products = models.ManyToManyField('Product', through='ServerProduct',
                                      related_name='products', blank=True)


class Product(TimeStampedModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45, unique=True)
    # ...
    servers = models.ManyToManyField(
        'Server', through='ServerProduct', related_name='servers')
```

In my view I have a form which allows users to create a Server and select from a list of all products for the Server to be associted with.

In order to create the `ServerProduct` objects (for the through table) on each save I have to write the following code inside `save()`.

```
class ServerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Server
        fields = '__all__'

    def save(self, commit=True):
        instance = super(ServerForm, self).save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        if instance.products.count():
            instance.products.clear()
        for product in self.cleaned_data['products']:
            ServerProduct.objects.create(server=instance, product=product)
        return instance
```

I want to be able to reuse the form for both `Create` and `Update` views. Hence why I have to check if the current Server is associated with any products, and then do `instance.products.clear()`. To make sure it removes any previous products if they get deselected by a user.

This entire process feels unecessary, especially when I've read a lot about Django's built-in `form.save_m2m()` method. My question is, is there a simpler way do achieve what I'm doing using Django built-in's?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django m2m form save " through " table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074938/django-m2m-form-save-through-table)

Comment: And you're sure this isn't working out of the box with the form returned by  `modelform_factory(model=Server)`? One form is used by Django for Create and Update, it should handle both cases just fine. That is what the Django Admin would use, and you can edit m2m relationships there without additional code.